# Can't ping to OpenVPN server

Tags: vpn, openvpn

In my office, I am trying to connect Raspberry Pi as a client to OpenVPN server(Ubuntu 14.04.3).

My Raspberry Pi's(client) ip is 10.1.2.14 & Server's ip is 10.1.2.12

When I execute following command from Raspberry Pi

```
openvpn --config pi2.ovpn
```

I get following logs on console

```
OpenVPN 2.3.4 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan 23 2016
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.08
Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
UDPv4 link local: [undef]
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.1.2.12:1194
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]10.1.2.12:1194, sid=e6eaaa4e 99903945
VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=IN, ST=MH, L=NaviMumbai, O=mycompany, OU=Java, CN=mycompany CA, name=server, emailAddress=bhushan.patil@mycompany.co.in
VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=IN, ST=MH, L=NaviMumbai, O=mycompany, OU=Java, CN=server, name=server, emailAddress=bhushan.patil@mycompany.co.in
Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
[server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]10.1.2.12:1194
SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.1.1.253/255.255.252.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=b8:27:eb:6d:4b:d6
TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
/sbin/ip route add 10.1.2.12/32 via 10.1.1.253
/sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
/sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
/sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But after this, when i ping to OpenVPN server (ping 10.8.0.1), I don't get reply.

I have same configuration for /etc/network/interfaces on both system(except their own ip)

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.2.12 #and 10.1.2.14 on pi
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 10.1.1.253
dns-nameservers 10.1.1.211 10.1.1.212
search domain mycompany.co.in
```

I am suspecting this issue has something to do with my company network coz when I did same procedure at my home, it was working. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**: After some time, I am getting this msg on console

```
Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Restart pause, 2 second(s)
```

**EDIT:** If I change protocol to TCP from UDP, then I can ping. I don't know why it is not working with UDP.

Comment: I might be reading wrongly but it looks like the vpn server is on 10.8.0.5, not 0.1

Comment: @djsmiley2k I don't think so, strange thing is that, it is working on TCP but not on UDP.